# Lefthanded-Orientation for Wacom Intuos Pro M on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS does not change direction of cursor movement

Tags: tablet, cursor, wacom

Tablet Wacom Intuos Pro M on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS is set for left-hand control.
In the 'Map Buttons' settings the buttons are correctly displayed on screen on the right-hand side if Left-Handed orientation is selected (and on the left-hand side if Left-Handed Orientation is unselected), but these settings have no effect on the direction of the cursor movements.
Whatever option is selected, the cursor always moves opposite to finger movement on the tablet pad like for Right-Handed set-up.
I have restarted the PC but it has no effect.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: Z97X-UD5H v: N/A serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z97X-UD5H v: x.x serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: F10 date: 08/03/2015 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-4790 bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Haswell rev: 3 L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 57467 
  Speed: 898 MHz min/max: 800/4000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 944 2: 932 
  3: 929 4: 912 5: 918 6: 977 7: 939 8: 936 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics 
  vendor: Gigabyte driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] vendor: eVga.com. 
  driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: nouveau 
  resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: NV120 v: 4.3 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
  Device-2: Intel 9 Series Family HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
  Device-3: NVIDIA GM200 High Definition Audio vendor: eVga.com. 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
  Device-4: C-Media CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio] vendor: ASUSTeK Virtuoso 100 
  driver: snd_virtuoso v: kernel bus ID: 07:04.0 
  Device-5: Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 type: USB 
  driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus ID: 3-3.1:3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-48-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I217-V vendor: Gigabyte driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k 
  port: f080 bus ID: 00:19.0 
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Gigabyte 
  driver: alx v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 278.03 GiB (29.8%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Smart Modular Tech. model: SHGP31-1000GM-2 
  size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 913.74 GiB used: 277.81 GiB (30.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1 
  ID-2: /boot size: 704.5 MiB used: 210.7 MiB (29.9%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
  ID-3: swap-1 size: 976.0 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nouveau temp: 29 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nouveau fan: 570 
Info:
  Processes: 279 Uptime: 14m Memory: 31.18 GiB used: 2.39 GiB (7.7%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Just to clarify. You said "Whatever option is selected, the cursor always moves opposite to finger movement on the tablet pad like for Right-Handed set-up." Is your issue with touch input, or do you also have a problem with pen input? GNOME (annoyingly) does not rotate a tablet's touch input, but pen input should be rotated correctly. You may need to run something like `xsetwacom set <id> rotate half` to rotate the touch device separately.

Comment: @jigpu This is quite surprising indeed. I just tested the pend input and the cursor moves directionally according to the pen movement, but in opposite direction when I use finger input.

Comment: @jigpu also I am not sure what I should replace <id> with in the code line. Don't find nay such peripheral id for the tablet.

Comment: Use `xsetwacom list` to get a list of all Wacom devices and then use the quoted name of the touch device as the <id> in the command above. For example, on my system I'd use "Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch" since that is the touch device listed for my tablet.

Comment: @jigpu Brilliant, thank you.
Finger touch is the right device to rotate.

username:~$ xsetwacom list
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pad pad       id: 15 type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen stylus    id: 16 type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen eraser    id: 17 type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen cursor    id: 18 type: CURSOR    
Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch  id: 19 type: TOUCH     
username:~$ xsetwacom set 15 rotate half
Property 'Wacom Rotation' does not exist on device.
username:~$ xsetwacom set 19 rotate half
username:~$